# where is PHP code interpreted?

Tags: php

where is PHP code interpreted?

Comment: Mind being a little more specific? Exactly what do you mean by "where"?

Comment: On the server side by the web server. You might have installed apache, right? Read about it.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how you have PHP set up. PHP will function as a webserver SAPI module, an executable CGI binary, or a standalone executable.

Answer (score 2):

typically, server-side as a webserver module. What's the context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I may be missing something, but your question seems very vague.  I hope this is the answer you are looking for:

PHP code is most commonly interpreted on a web server, but it can be used to write desktop applications and interpreted there.